# mysql select to join with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: sites, features, and site_feature
the "sites" table like this:
sites

```
+-----+--------+
|id   | name   | 
+-----+--------+
| 1   | site1  | 
| 2   | site2  |
| 3   | site3  |
| 4   | site4  |
| 5   | site5  |
| 6   | site6  |
| 7   | site7  |
| 8   | site8  |
+-----+--------+
```

the "features" table like this:
features

```
+-----+--------+
|id   | feature| 
+-----+--------+
| 1   | fea1   | 
| 2   | fea2   |
| 3   | fea3   |
| 4   | fea4   |
| 5   | fea5   |
| 6   | fea6   |
| 7   | fea7   |
| 8   | fea8   |
+-----+--------+
```

the "site_feature" table like this:
site_feature

```
+-----+--------+------------+
|id   | site_id| feature_id | 
+-----+--------+------------+
| 1   | 1      | 1          |
| 2   | 1      | 4          | 
| 3   | 2      | 1          | 
| 4   | 2      | 2          | 
| 5   | 2      | 5          | 
| 6   | 3      | 1          | 
| 7   | 3      | 4          | 
| 8   | 4      | 7          | 
| 9   | 5      | 8          | 
+-----+--------+------------+
```

I want to get sites which have multiple features I choose, for example I want list the sites with both feature fea1 and fea4.

how to build this query? 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want sites with two specific features and the sites can have other features as well as the two specified, then use `group by` with `having`:

```
select sf.site_id
from site_feature sf join
     feature f
     on sf.feature_id = f.id
where f.feature in ('fea1', 'fea4')
group by sf.site_id
having count(distinct f.feature) = 2;
```

If you want to extend this to additional features, add them into the `where` clause list and increment the value `2`.

Comment: i guess it would be better to use >= 2

Comment: Thanks, I want to list the site_id with both fea1 and fea4, not either one of them, is there any easy solution?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid No, the answer is correct.

Comment: @user3613815 . . . That is what this query does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY operation, as below:

```
SELECT
  site_id, 
  count(*)
FROM site_feature
GROUP BY site_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Here is [**MySQL Reference Manual link**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for GROUP functions.